# Ignore files auto modified during making Linux SDK

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

I am working on Project which uses Linux buildroot SDK.
Whenever I build new image some files stamp and content changes by make system. 
I can see files list changed and want to ignore this files somehow.

How easily can I add this all files into the `.gitignore` file directly?

Comment: Do you save those images in specific folder?

Comment: Could you include an example list of those files, like the Unstaged section in the `git status` output?